# on category page get name of category as a string

Tags: php, categories

On my category pages, I would like to get the name of the current category, compare it with the values of an array and display it (as a page header, but *without a link* on it), if the name is identical to one of the strings in the array (meaning: on certain category pages I *want* to display the category name as a title, on others *not*). All that *above/outside* the loop.

I tried this (inside `category.php`):

```
<?php
    $visible_titles = array("string1", "string2", "string3");
    if(in_array(the_category(), $visible_titles)) {
        echo "<h1>";
        the_category();
        echo "</h1>";
    }
?>
```

But from that I get a wrong result: 
- The category name is displayed as a link even if it's not in the array
- The content of the if-clause is never echoed

I also tried to use `single_cat_title();`, but that (just like `the_category`) also just echoes the category name as a link – I can't use it as a string to compare it to the values in my array, and I can't display it without it being a link.

What template tag or function can I use to get the desired result?

Comment: may I know the reason for the downvote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

read https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/single_cat_title/

set the `$display` parameter to `false`;

i.e. use: 
`if(in_array( single_cat_title( '', false ), $visible_titles)) {`

Comment: Thank you very much! Actually I had read the page you linked to and tried that, but I must have made some typo or other mistake. Thanks again!